# ./pycharm.sh failed to load in fedora 26

Tags: pycharm, x11

I am trying to run pycharm.sh in Fedora, but it's showing following:

```
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Failed to initialize graphics environment

    java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
        at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:128)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1049)
        at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
        at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
        at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
        at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
        at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:105)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my research:

- Fedora 26 uses Wayland instead of X11 ([since v25](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_25_talking_points)).
- PyCharm Wayland support is pretty sketchy

Workarounds

- [Try using the X11 windowing system](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/96134/how-can-i-set-xorg-as-a-default-on-fedora-25/)
- Give up on running PyCharm and try something else like [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor))